# I am check numbers mp3 file and numbers folder for item in android

Tags: android

I am very tired to use coding for show number mp3 file and numbers folder for item but item show numbers all file and folder for item.
this code

```
File[]dirs = f.listFiles();
        this.setTitle(""+f.getName());//File show in Action Bar
        List<Item>dir = new ArrayList<Item>();
        List<Item>fls = new ArrayList<Item>();
        try{
            for(File ff: dirs)
            {
                Date lastModDate = new Date(ff.lastModified());
                DateFormat formater = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance();
                String date_modify = formater.format(lastModDate);
                if(ff.isDirectory()) {
                        File[] fbuf = ff.listFiles();
                        int buf = 0;
                        if (fbuf != null) {
                            buf = fbuf.length;
                        } else buf = 0;
                        String num_item = String.valueOf(buf);
                        if (buf == 0) num_item = num_item + " item";
                        else num_item = num_item + " items";
//String formated = lastModDate.toString();
                        dir.add(new
                                Item(ff.getName(), num_item, null, ff.getAbsolutePath(), "directory_icon"));
                    }
```

`

Comment: I advice you using a more clear explanation othervise down votes will come :( .